# Nodejs Exception not catch by async function

Tags: node.js

I'm facing an issue with this code below

```
const mariadb = require('mariadb');
const pool = mariadb.createPool({
    ...
});

var conn = null;

async function getRegisterInfo(token){
    try {
        conn = await pool.getConnection();
        const rows = await conn.query('SELECT * FROM users_pending WHERE token = ?;', [token]);
        if(rows.length == 0)
            throw 404;
        return rows[0];
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        throw err;
    } finally {
        if (conn) return conn.end();
    }
}

var token = "dzdz"
getRegisterInfo(token).then(data=>{
    console.log("Data:"+data)
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log("Error:"+err)
})
```

Here is console output

```
# node test.js
404
Data:undefined
```

The fact is that this token doesn't exist, so the exception 404 is raised because the length of rows is equal to 0, as you can see, the catch inside the function is correctly called because the message "404" is logged. But the exception is not forward... It should also print "Error:404", instead of "Data: undefined".

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

In your finally you are returning. Change your code to this

```js
finally {
  if (conn) conn.end();
}
```

Read [Returning from a finally-block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#returning_from_a_finally-block)